# validateForm.validate is not a function из-за чего возникает эта ошика?

Tags: php, jquery

Работаю с Yii. Пытаюсь подключить плагин validate. В итоге как бы я не пытался, где бы не подключал, получаю ошибку validateForm.validate is not a function в чем проблем?

```
use app\widgets\Alert;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use app\assets\AppAsset;

AppAsset::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?php $this->registerCsrfMetaTags() ?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
    <script src='/../../web/index.js' type="module"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
```

index.js

```
$(document).on('click', '.send', function() {
    alert("232");
    var validateForm = $(document).find('#contacsform');
    validateForm.validate({
        rules: {
            fromPerson: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            fromPlace: {
                required: true,                
                minlength: 5
            },
            toPerson:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            toPlace:{
                required: true,                
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        messages: {
            fromPerson: {
                required: "Введите Ваше Имя",
                minlength: "Имя должно быть более 2-х символов"
                
            }            
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {                
            form.submit();
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {                 
            var item = element.parents('.item');
            item.append(error);
        }
    });
 
    validateForm.submit();
});
```

Comment: В web/index.js вы пытаетесь что-то провалидировать сразу при загрузке страницы?

Comment: @vp_arth я отредактировал вопрос. Добавил туда index.js